# How can I enable external access to my Kubernetes service via the master with Calico on GCP?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, calico

I have a one master and one worker Kubernetes cluster with Calico deployed from [here](https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.5/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/calico#installing-with-the-kubernetes-api-datastore50-nodes-or-less) with no changes to the manifests. The master has an internal IP address of `10.132.0.30` and I am trying to expose my service (running on the worker) on the master as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  externalIPs: [10.132.0.30]
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: nginx
```

`curl http://10.132.0.30` from the master works as expected, but curling the master from my laptop on its external IP address hangs, even though I can see connections using `tcpdump`:

```
# tcpdump -i eth0 dst 10.132.0.30 and dst port 80
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
22:52:16.692059 IP cpc102582-walt20-2-0-cust85.13-2.cable.virginm.net.62882 > fail5-luke-master.c.jetstack-luke.internal.http: Flags [S], seq 3014275997, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 181016377 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
...
```

Running other `tcpdump` commands on other interfaces seems that packets are reaching nginx but not returning (`cali3561fc118c0` is the interface of my nginx Pod on the worker in the root network namespace and `192.168.1.4` is its assigned IP):

```
# tcpdump -i cali3561fc118c0 dst 192.168.1.4
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on cali3561fc118c0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
23:00:23.626170 IP 192.168.0.1.65495 > 192.168.1.4.http-alt: Flags [S], seq 2616662679, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 181480911 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
...
```

I guess there are many possible problems but is there anything obvious I am missing?

EDIT: I have followed the advice from the Calico docs [here](https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.5/reference/public-cloud/gce) with no luck

Kubernetes version: 1.13.4

Answer (score 0):

I hadn't set the `--cluster-cidr` on `kube-proxy`. Setting this meant that `kube-proxy` knew to masquerade external traffic as otherwise the return path would be asymmetric (it was always bouncing off-node to the worker): https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/proxy/iptables/proxier.go#L841-L845